# How to apply CSS to only a part of text inside a textbox?

Tags: jquery, css

I have several textboxes which appear as shown below, I would like to apply some styles to the   word preceding the colons:

Can someone please suggest how this could be achieved?
[image]

Comment: Can the value be changed? How do you plan to handle that?

Comment: Can you post your html code?

Comment: Can you crop your image?

Comment: If that's an input element, you can't style only part of the value. It's all or nothing!

Comment: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you're trying to break the placeholder in two and and apply different style and that can't be done.

Try this approach:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Batman" />
    </fieldset>
<form>
```

This way you can apply two different styles on each element. 
The `placeholder`, can be style but it doesn't work on all browsers. and the `placeholder` **attribute is HTML5**.

Comment: Thanks Axente! but i have a limitation not to split the values and use a fieldset

Comment: @ronanmarsh Then it's all or nothing as adeneo stated above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div contenteditable='true' 
style="width:225px;height:23px;border:1px solid black">
<span>Nome a Cigonome :</span>
entry of user
```

```
span{
background-color:yellow;    
}
```